# QMap<int,QByteArray> return Wrong QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt, qmap

I am using

```
QMap < int, QByteArray> RegTable; (Seprate Class Variable)
```

to storing Modbus Register Address and data received from  Serial Port. Everything working fine, data read from the serial port and fill to the QByteArray correctly.

```
qDebug() << Modbus->RegTable[RegAddr].toHex(' ');
```

print the correct data. But if want to write variable using it then always the same value/Garbage stored in this variable.

```
    unsigned int unixTimeStamp = 0;
    qDebug() << Modbus->RegTable[RegAddr].toHex(' ');

    unixTimeStamp  = static_cast <unsigned int>Modbus->RegTable[RegAddr].at(4);
    unixTimeStamp |= static_cast <unsigned int>Modbus->RegTable[RegAddr].at(5)<<8;
    unixTimeStamp |= static_cast <unsigned int>Modbus->RegTable[RegAddr].at(6)<<16;
    unixTimeStamp |= static_cast <unsigned int>Modbus->RegTable[RegAddr].at(7)<<24;

    QDateTime timestamp;
    timestamp.setTime_t(unixTimeStamp  );
    qDebug() << timestamp.toString(Qt::SystemLocaleShortDate); //wrong time
```

RegTable is Modbus Class variable, And I used it to the main class but always I get the wrong data or values.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
unixTimeStamp |= ...;
```

you write to the same byte over and over again. You need to shift the values:

```
unixTimeStamp  = static_cast <unsigned int>Modbus->RegTable[RegAddr].at(4) << 24;
unixTimeStamp |= static_cast <unsigned int>Modbus->RegTable[RegAddr].at(5) << 16;
unixTimeStamp |= static_cast <unsigned int>Modbus->RegTable[RegAddr].at(6) <<  8;
unixTimeStamp |= static_cast <unsigned int>Modbus->RegTable[RegAddr].at(7);
```

Of course, the shifts might have to be done in the opposite order depending on byte order.

Comment: The TimeStamp value is changed in 1 second but unixTimeStamp always store 4294967239        **void MainWindow::UpdateCustomUI(short regAddr)
{
    if(regAddr == 30000)
    {
        xxunixTimeStamp = 0;
        QByteArray temp_d = modbus->QRegTable[regAddr];
        xxunixTimeStamp  = temp_d[4];
        xxunixTimeStamp |= temp_d[5]<<8;
        xxunixTimeStamp |= temp_d[6]<<16;
        xxunixTimeStamp |= temp_d[7]<<24;
        QDateTime timestamp;
        timestamp.setTime_t(xxunixTimeStamp);
        qDebug() << timestamp.toString(Qt::SystemLocaleShortDate);
    }

}**